# SVG - How animate motion several elements contemporaneously?

Tags: svg

I need to animate more then one svg elements, and I'm using this construction:

```
<g>
        <circle cx="" cy="" r="7" class="pulse">
            <animateMotion dur="25s" repeatCount="indefinite">
                <mpath xlink:href="#t1" />
            </animateMotion>
        </circle>

        <circle cx="" cy="" r="7">
            <animateMotion dur="25s" repeatCount="indefinite">
                <mpath xlink:href="#t1" />
            </animateMotion>
        </circle>
    </g>
```

It's working fine, but I have more than 100 elements, that need to animate. Can I use animateMotion to group? Or maybe for more then one element contemporaneously?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only animate one element at a time but that element can be a container such as a `<g>` in which case all the contents will animate.

```html
<svg width="150" height="150" viewBox="0 0 150 150"
>
  <defs>
    <path d="M10,110 A120,120 -45 0,1 110 10 A120,120 -45 0,1 10,110" id="t1"/>
  </defs>

  <g>
    <animateMotion dur="25s" repeatCount="indefinite">
      <mpath xlink:href="#t1" />
    </animateMotion>
    <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="7" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="25" cy="5" r="7"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Robert Longson rightly said that at one point in time you can run only one object or one group of objects with the command `animateMotion`

But using the commands `textPath`,`animate` and `unicode characters`, you can simultaneously run as many objects as you like.

Such an effect can be compared to the effect of a moving string of letters, but it is always possible to position individual objects of motion using `dx ="x"` `dy ="y"` inside the tags `<tspan>`

```html
<svg width="600" height="400" viewBox="100 100 400 300">

 <path id="pathTrain" d="M100,200 C100,100 250,100 250,200 S 400,300 400,200" stroke="grey" fill="none"/>

<text font-size="32"  font-family="Times New Roman" fill="black" >
<textPath id="result"    xlink:href="#pathTrain">
<tspan dx="0" > &#128645; </tspan> <tspan dx="-15">  &#128643; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#128643;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#7441; </tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-15"> &#7441;</tspan><tspan dx="-15">   &#45; </tspan><tspan dx="-12">&#128643;</tspan>
<animate  dur="10s" repeatCount="2" attributeName="startOffset" values="55%;1%;55%"/> 
</textPath>
</text>    
   
</svg>
```